Playstore review was rejected due to permissions
I am using react-native for the application.
But it was rejected due to this reason.

But I am no longer added these permissions. I was removing the some permissions via tools:node="remove"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:node="remove" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove" />

For the bundle details

What I am missing?
Thank you.

Found the solution.
I edited the rollout percentage and make it 100%.
The issue was, it was 1% and they are still validating the previous builds on the production.
It is approved now.
Thanks
